# is there an alternative to usbkill or silk-guardian in Debian?

Tags: debian, security, usb, usb-drive, alternatives

I saw [usbkill](https://github.com/hephaest0s/usbkill) and [silk-guardian](https://github.com/NateBrune/silk-guardian) sometime back. I specifically like the whole shutdown or whatever I want to be done if a usb key is inserted which isn't whitelisted before. Does anybody of any alternative software which has the same/similar functionality in Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [usbguard](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/usbguard):

> USB device authorization policy framework
>
> The USBGuard software framework helps to protect your computer against
>   rogue USB devices (a.k.a. BadUSB) by implementing basic whitelisting
>   and blacklisting capabilities based on device attributes.

There's also a GUI available with [usbguard-applet-qt](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/usbguard-applet-qt):

> This package contains the qt-applet for controlling usbguard.

All this won't protect the computer from an [USB Kill](https://usbkill.com/) key, unless an electrical safety device is used between.