# Allow attaching only storage devices on specific USB port?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, usb

I want to allow attaching of storage medias like flash-drive or external disk to a specific USB port and restrict any other types of devices especially Keyboard and Mouse to that particular USB port. How can I achieve this?

Comment: these might help: [is there an alternative to usbkill or silk-guardian in Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440495/is-there-an-alternative-to-usbkill-or-silk-guardian-in-debian/440498#440498)

Comment: Or if you want to do it directly: udev-rules (google for tutorials). Also have a look at `lsusb -t` to identify the port chain, you need to take internal hubs into account.